# How to make night effect and empower car with extra lights

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, perspective, lighting-effects

I'm new to design and it would be great if you could help me out here.

I have a photo of a car:
[image]

and I want to make a very realistic effect of night and put some extra, cool lights on top of the car, and make some sort of realistic light from it and how is it lighting the path for the car in the darkness :) I'm like super excited and trying everything around, but all I'm getting is very, very unrealistic effects... besides, I don't know how to make some things like this one below(with perspective) and would be glad if you could tell me how should I do this.

So, I took this image of lights
[image]

But didn't know how to make a right perspective(tried the "perspective" transform, but it didn't help much)

Thanks in advance!

I can't post any more links because of my reputation, so I decided to give you one more photo:

[image]

Comment: It's traditional to show what you've tried and detail where you are having problems rather than merely asking someone to write you a custom tutorial.

Comment: I deleted my night version and will try to make new one. I'm correctly selecting at this moment the lighting bar for the car, but that's difficult :) And how to make the light path from the lighting bar I have no clue at all, I tried to googled it, but nothing even close to something normal

Answer (score 1):

Had some time on my hands so I gave this a shot. I intentionally dropped the quality of it so you can improve your skills by doing this on your own.

[image: Original image edited to help OP learn.]

Really all I did was:

1. Lasso tool to cut out sky.
2. Placed in a night sky image.
3. Duplicated and overlayed the car layer.
4. Desaturated the image.
5. Applied shadows by using a large brush around the edges.
6. Used a small white brush to make the appearance of the headlights and overhead light being on.
7. Made some light beams with a larger white brush and dropped the opacity.

As for the overhead light, play around with the Edit > Perspective Warp tool. You'll get the hang of it, just use common sense.